# Tree datastructure with 2 different key types and minimal redundant code

Tags: c, generics, tree

I'm programming a prefix tree in C to store IP-Prefixes.
The keys are the IP-Prefixes. 
I would like to use it with 32bit or 128bit keys (IPv4/IPv6 addresses).

The insert/remove/lookup functions need to call different bitop functions for the ipv4 or ipv6 variant.

How could I do this in C?

- The type of the key should'nt be determined at runtime.
- I want to compile to different versions of the datastructure one that works with IPv4 Prefixes and one for IPv6 Prefixes.
- I need to use both versions in the tree in the same C-file later.
- I would like to have minimal duplicate code

At the end i would like to have the following structs and functions:

```
  typedef struct tree_node6_t {
    ipv6_addr prefix;
    u_int8_t len;
    struct tree_node6_t* parent;
    struct tree_node6_t* lchild;
    struct tree_node6_t* rchild;
    void* data;
} tree_node6;

typedef struct tree_node4_t {
    ipv4_addr prefix;
    u_int8_t len;
    struct tree_node4_t* parent;
    struct tree_node4_t* lchild;
    struct tree_node4_t* rchild;
    void* data;
} tree_node;

void tree_insert4(tree_node* root, tree_node* new_node, const unsigned int level);
void tree_insert6(tree_node* root, tree_node* new_node, const unsigned int level);
tree_node* tree_lookup4(const tree_node* root_node, const ipv4_addr* prefix, const u_int8_t prefix_len, unsigned int* level);
tree_node* tree_lookup6(const tree_node* root_node, const ipv6_addr* prefix, const u_int8_t prefix_len, unsigned int* level);
```

thanks for any hints :=)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that every IPv4 address can be mapped to a IPv6 address.

Comment: yes, but storing 32bit adresses in  128bit ints is a huge memory waste (few hundred thousand node)

Answer (score 1):

You could use another typedef to declare the ip type.
Then you can just change that at compile time with preprocessor directives:

```
#ifdef USE_NODE4
typedef ipv4_addr ADDRESSTYPE ;
#define TREEINSERT tree_insert4 
#define TREELOOKUP tree_lookup4
#else
typedef ipv6_addr ADDRESSTYPE ;
#define TREEINSERT tree_insert6 
#define TREELOOKUP tree_lookup6
#endif

typedef struct tree_node_general {
    ADDRESSTYPE prefix;
    u_int8_t len;
    struct tree_node_general* parent;
    struct tree_node_general* lchild;
    struct tree_node_general* rchild;
    void* data;
} tree_node; 

void TREEINSERT (tree_node* root, tree_node* new_node, const unsigned int level);
tree_node* TREELOOKUP (const tree_node* root_node, const ADDRESSTYPE* prefix, const u_int8_t prefix_len, unsigned int* level);
```

Comment: define trickery is probably the way to go if you want to do everything at compile-time.

Comment: If I do this with defines. I would compile a function with the same name, eg tree_insert twice, with different defines set. But than I can't link one programm to both object files, because the symbol names for tree_insert are equal?

Comment: Easiest way to solve this is define a different namespace for each.

Comment: Right forgot about that. You could either have 2 separate dlls with different names, and explicitly import the functions. Or, put the method name in a #define as well: `#define TREEINSERT tree_insert4`

Comment: If i put the function name also in a define, I have also have to write duplicate code for tree_insert4 and tree_insert6. Can I append the value of a define to a function name?

Comment: Why duplicate code ? I've edited the answer with an example that defines the function names as well

Comment: I have to define the program code for the tree_insert4 and tree_insert6 functions. Both would have up to 99% the same code, except 2-3 calls to different functions.

Comment: Then define those.... you're starting to add information that's beyond this question. In general: if you have the same code, that all that's different is the name of a function that's being called, just define the name of the function for each compilation.